# Share a link and content with Google+ using an URL

Tags: google-plus

Is there any way I can share content and the link to the content to Google+ the way Facebook does, using just an URL?

With Facebook feed dialog, I can share content title, description and the URL. Is that possible with Google Plus? I did some searching and only found sharing of URL.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=458358780877780&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Google+ Share Link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink)

> The share link is intended for native client applications, Flash applications, highly privacy-sensitive sites, and others who may not be able to use the +1 or share button. Adding the following markup to your site will include a simple icon which will pop open a share dialog for your visitors.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

> Note: Replace {URL} with the URL of the page you want to share. You must properly escape any user-generated content that may occur within {URL}

If you just want a raw link, you can just use

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}
```

Just make sure you properly escape the "{URL}" value.

The only other thing you can add besides the URL to share is the language code for the language to be used on the share page.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7157411/21960

Comment: Thank you, I knew about stackoverflow's topic. However I can't see where should I add my textual content. If I press the G+ icon I get a popup with a "Add a comment" text area. How I can I open this popup with a message already in it? That was I meant with the word "content". This is something that can be done with twitter, for example (and FB, of course).

Comment: From the Google page on this topic, that doesn't look possible. It also jives with things I've heard them say, specifically they don't want G+ to turn into another place where people just pipe the same content; they want it to be unique.

Comment: Do not use `alt` on the `<a>` - [use `title` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621375/6439240)